# PCA for KNN in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pca

I've been tasked to implement my PCA code to convert data to a 2d field for a KNN assignment. My PCA code creates an array with the eigenvectors called PCevecs.

```
def __PCA(data):
   #Normalize data
   data_cent = data-np.mean(data)

   #calculate covariance
   covarianceMatrix = np.cov(data_cent, bias=True)

   #Find eigenvector and eigenvalue
   eigenvalue, eigenvector= np.linalg.eigh(covarianceMatrix)

   #Sorting the eigenvectors and eigenvalues:
   PCevals = eigenvalue[::-1]
   PCevecs = eigenvector[:,::-1]

   return PCevals, PCevecs
```

The assignment transforms the training-data using the PCA. The returned PCevecs has the shape (88, 88) given by calling print(PCevecs.shape). The shape of the training data is (88, 4).

```
np.dot(trainingFeatures, PCevecs[:, 0:2])
```

When the code is running I get the error message "ValueError: shapes (88,4) and (88,2) not alligned: 4 (dim 1) != 88 (dim 0)". I can see that the arrays don't match, but I can't see that I've done anything wrong with the PCA implementation. I've tried to have a look at similar problems on Stackoverflow. I haven't seen anyone sorting the eigenvector and eigenvalues the same way.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `np.dot()` operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**EDITED** with additional info from the comments)

While the PCA implementation is OK in general, you may want to either compute it on the data transposed, or you want to make sure that you tell [`np.cov()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) in which axis your dimensionality is via the `rowvar` parameter.

The following would work as you expect:

```
import numpy as np


def __PCA_fixed(data, rowvar=False):
   # Normalize data
   data_cent = data - np.mean(data)

   # calculate covariance (pass `rowvar` to `np.cov()`)
   covarianceMatrix = np.cov(data_cent, rowvar=rowvar, bias=True)  
   # Find eigenvector and eigenvalue
   eigenvalue, eigenvector= np.linalg.eigh(covarianceMatrix)

   # Sorting the eigenvectors and eigenvalues:
   PCevals = eigenvalue[::-1]
   PCevecs = eigenvector[:,::-1]

   return PCevals, PCevecs
```

Testing it out with some random numbers:

```
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 10))
PCevals, PCevecs = __PCA_fixed(data)
print(PCevecs.shape)
# (10, 10)
```

Also note that, in more general terms, the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) ([`np.linalg.svd()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) in NumPy) might be a better approach for [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (with a [simple relationship with the eigenvalue decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition) you use and transposition).

---

As a general coding style note, it may be a good idea to follow the advice from [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), many of which can be readily checked by some automated tool like, e.g. [`autopep8`](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/).

Comment: <code> np.dot(trainingFeatures, PCevecs[:,0:2] <code> is given in the assignment. Would be weird if I have to change part of the backbone. I thought by calculating the eigenvector and taking the dot product, you would project the data onto what in this case would be a 2D field. Could you elaborate on the slicing of the array?

Comment: It might help if I specify the assignment text a bit. It says "Use PCA to convert data from 4D to 2D by perserving only 2 most representative eigenvector" The dataset is an iris flower database. There are 3 iris types, and each is characterized with 4 attributes.